# How To Speed Up lein Uberjar Build

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure "main" application that depends on several Clojure libraries, two of which are mine. The compile phase, whether just compiling or running uberjar takes a long time. It's on the order of at least one minute or more. Neither of my libraries nor main are very large.

My libraries' and main project.clj files contain

```
  :aot [bene-cmp.core]
  :omit-source true
```

directives.

What can I do, if anything, to speed up the build process?

Here are the three project.clj files.
project.clj main

```
;$Log$
;
(defproject bene-cmp "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "This is the main benetrak/GIC comparison program."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.2.4"]
                 [seesaw "1.4.0"]
                 [bene-csv "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [util "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :aot [bene-cmp.core]
  :omit-source true
  :main bene-cmp.core)
```

project.clj library 1

```
(defproject util "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    ;$Log: project.clj,v $
    ;Revision 1.3  2012/04/04 18:24:36  cvsuser
    ;Take II on comments. (comment ) does not work.
    ;
    ;Revision 1.2  2012/04/04 18:20:54  cvsuser
    ;New library for Clojure. Add CVS comments.

  :description "A general purposes Clojure library"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]]
  :aot [util.core]
  :omit-source true)
```

project.clj library 2

```
(defproject bene-csv "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ;$Log: project.clj,v $
  ;Revision 1.2  2012/04/05 22:50:24  cvsuser
  ;Update and add cvs logging.
  ;
  :description "A csv parsing library"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [util "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :aot [bene-csv.core]
  :omit-source true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setup jvm option -Xmx to 2G or above.

Comment: Thanks, but the build speed is about the same. I've added   :jvm-opts ["-Xmx1G"] to my main and my dependent libraries. It was good to learn about this, though, +1.